# Is there a minimum number of days a Canadian must spend in Canada before returning to the US?

Tags: air-travel, usa, regulations, canadian-citizens

Is there a requirement that says how long I have to be in Canada before I can go back to US? My situation is: I just got back to Canada not too long ago, but was notified there is a conference in a 5 days. Is possible that I can go back?

Comment: ok, thanks. I am solely worried that they will reject me because I didn't stay in CAD for a certain about of time.

Comment: @pnuts Make it into an answer.

Comment: btw this is all using b2 visa. So, I should be ok right?

Comment: @JOY: Canadian citizens generally do not get B2 visas. Canadian citizens can already enter without a visa into B2 status by showing up to the border.

Comment: yes,i know b2 is not really a visa but I can still go back in such a short amount of time right? I am only asking because i don't want the border to think that i want to stay there for long.

Comment: ps: mine is a social conferece..

Comment: btw again, yes. it is a b-2 to travel mainly and a conference or fair or some sort of convention? (vlogger fair)

Comment: Also, you should stop trying to be confusing. Please just state explicitly whether you are Canadian or another nationality, and what visa you have (if any).

Comment: @pnuts Yes, I noticed that, which is why this really doesn't make sense. Canadians may be admitted under B1 or B2 _status_, and their stamp will be the same as a visa holder, but they aren't required to actually get the visa.